# How to authenticate a Web API to call Graph API with a token acquired by a client App

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, access-token

I am developing a client (React, typescript) application and a server (.Net Core) application. The api should make some calls to the microsoft graph api.

I have registered both apps in the Azure Active Directory and exposed the api with a permission. So on client side I am getting an access_token using msal.js with the given scope:

`scopes = ["api://clientId/Test"]`

So I am able to authorize in the api.

1. How should I gain access on the api side to consume the graph api?
   Should I request a token in the client with `scopes = ["User.Read", "api://clientId/Test"]`?
2. Is it right what am doing to register the server app in azure as well? In the end could I have a token with only the scopes of Graph like `scopes = ["User.Read", "Email.Read"]` pass it to the Api and use this token on the api side to access graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I found that the solution was to use the [on-behalf-of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).

So basically an access token is retrieved from the client app with the scope that grants authorization over the server app. Then the server app is using this access token to create access tokens to get authorization for the Graph API.

Here the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph) I used.